# How can I track my days activities on Android (Similar to Track and Share on iPhone)?

Tags: applications

There is a app called ["Track and Share"](http://www.trackandshareapps.com/) available for iPhone.

This app helps us track as to how we spend our day, doing what activities and doing what category of activities.

I wonder how I could do the same on Android. Maybe a similar app exists?

Comment: Could you please add a description of the app (or, especially, of the features you find most important) to the question? It'll save us all time searching around their website wondering what the app does. And of course, we might guess the wrong features as important to you.

Comment: @derobert I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many for Android, this two seem to perform the tasks mentioned by "Track and Share" *(additionally, you can check the left column from Google Play Store for related apps)*:

- [Time Recording - Timesheet App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamicg.timerecording)

  > Timesheet manager - easy to use, highly adaptive. Manage your timesheet.
  >
  > - Check in & out
  > - Task assignment
  > - Daily & detailed notes
  > - Overview of day, week, month
  > - Data export & email as CSV, HTML or XML
  > - Integrated backup & restore

  Check the [Lifehacker review](http://lifehacker.com/5853644/the-best-time-tracking-application-for-android).

  [image: Time Recording]

---

- [Daily Task Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glen.apps.DailyTasks)

  > Keep track of your tasks that you repeat on a daily basis.
  >
  > This app allows the user to keep track of daily tasks that are important to them. Add each task and then throughout the day or at the end of the day check off the ones that were completed.

  [image: Daily Task Tracker]